# Spring @Transactional not working after migrating to Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-transactions, spring-aspects

I have recently upgraded application from Spring 4.3.x and JDK 8 with AspectJ 1.8.10 to JDK 17 with Spring 5.3.x and AspectJ 1.9.20.1 and Transactional annotation seems to be not working

In application configuration there is

```xml
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" mode="aspectj"/>
<context:load-time-weaver/>
```

I tried defining AnnotationTransactionAspect, changing AspectJ version but nothing seems to help resolve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You did not even post any log output. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the ["Use LTW on Java 16+"](https://github.com/eclipse-aspectj/aspectj/blob/master/docs/release/README-1.9.21.adoc#use-ltw-on-java-16) part of the release notes? For load-time weaving, you need to add `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` to your JVM command line.